# MySql GROUP_CONCAT as Filter Query

Tags: mysql

I have two table X & Y:

Table X

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "a,b,c,d" |
| 2 | "b,c" |
| 3 | "a,c,d" |
| 4 | "a,b,c" |
| 5 | "a,d" |
| 6 | "b,d" |

Table Y

| id | Filter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "a,d" |

And I want to get join table contain "a" & "d", result :

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "a,b,c,d" |
| 3 | "a,c,d" |
| 5 | "a,d" |

-- I have tried this:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `x`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `x` 
SELECT 1 as id, "a,b,c,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 2 as id, "b,c" as `value`
UNION SELECT 3 as id, "a,c,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 4 as id, "a,b,c" as `value`
UNION SELECT 5 as id, "a,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 6 as id, "b,d" as `value`;
SELECT * FROM x;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `y`; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `y` 
SELECT 1 as id, "a,d" as `filter`;
SELECT * FROM y;
 
SELECT x.id, x.`value`
FROM `x`
JOIN `y` ON x.`value` LIKE CONCAT('%', y.`filter`, '%');
```

-- But the result only get id '5', 'a,d'.

Comment: Despite `a,d` containing a comma it is a SINGLE string. You are (wrongly) assuming the like operator will divide that single sting into 2 parts, looking for `like '%a%' and like '%d%'`  but that just isn't going to happen. The reason you get 5 as the result is as it is the only row that matches to "a,d" (as a single string). i.e. there is no magic just because there is a comma.

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('a,b,c,d', '(a*d)')

Answer (score 1):

Using comma-separated values are tricky to query and hard to maintain. It's wise of you deciding to separate them into rows. 
But just in case the orginal data cannot be modified, we do have a way to separate the values into rows on the fly by using recursive CTE, which is available since MySQL 8.0 .

Note:Table structure and data are based on the original set. No additional table is required, but let's add another row in table y so we can further test our query later on.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS x; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x SELECT 1 as id, "a,b,c,d" as value UNION SELECT 2 as id, "b,c" as value UNION SELECT 3 as id, "a,c,d" as value UNION SELECT 4 as id, "a,b,c" as value UNION SELECT 5 as id, "a,d" as value UNION SELECT 6 as id, "b,d" as value; SELECT * FROM x;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS y; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE y SELECT 1 as id, "a,d" as filter union select 2 as id,"a,c,d" as filter;  

SELECT * FROM y;

-- result
+----+--------+
| id | filter |
+----+--------+
|  1 | a,d    |
|  2 | a,c,d  |
+----+--------+
```

Now let's use the recursive CTE to turn comma-separated values into rows for our desired y.id (here we use your original data of y.id=1):

```
with recursive cte as
    (select substring_index(filter,',',1) as f,
    substring(filter,length(substring_index(filter,',',1))+2) as remainder,
    @row_count:=1
    from y where id=1 -- Here we define the desired id in table y 
    union all
    select substring_index(remainder,',',1) ,
    substring(remainder,length(substring_index(remainder,',',1))+2),
    @row_count:=@row_count+1 
    from cte
    where length(remainder)>0
    )
select f,@row_count from cte
;

-- result
+------+------------+
| f    | @row_count |
+------+------------+
| a    | 2          |
| d    | 2          |
+------+------------+
```

As you can see above, I also created a user variable which stores the total row count for the separated rows. The rest is just the search and compare job between our derived cte table and table x:

```
with recursive cte as
    (select substring_index(filter,',',1) as f,
    substring(filter,length(substring_index(filter,',',1))+2) as remainder,
    @row_count:=1
    from y where id=1
    union all
    select substring_index(remainder,',',1) ,
    substring(remainder,length(substring_index(remainder,',',1))+2),
    @row_count:=@row_count+1 
    from cte
    where length(remainder)>0
    )
select * from x where     
( select count(*) from cte where locate(f, value)>0 )  = @row_count
; 

-- result 
+----+---------+
| id | value   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a,b,c,d |
|  3 | a,c,d   |
|  5 | a,d     |
+----+---------+
```

As displayed above, we have the right output. Now let's test the same query using y.id=2:

```
with recursive cte as
    (select substring_index(filter,',',1) as f,
    substring(filter,length(substring_index(filter,',',1))+2) as remainder,
    @row_count:=1
    from y where id=2
    union all
    select substring_index(remainder,',',1) ,
    substring(remainder,length(substring_index(remainder,',',1))+2),
    @row_count:=@row_count+1 
    from cte
    where length(remainder)>0
    )
select * from x where     
( select count(*) from cte where locate(f, value)>0 )  = @row_count
; 

-- result set:
+----+---------+
| id | value   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a,b,c,d |
|  3 | a,c,d   |
+----+---------+
```

**UPDATED SECTION**

For MySQL versions prior to 8.0, it's still possible to do it. But unlike the one using recursive CTE in which all you need to do is define the required y.id, this one involves manual creating of sequence table by using union statements. The sequence table will be used to provide adequate rows for the comma-separated string after the string is separated into rows. Below is the query to get the rows for the string. (The string is not separated at the moment for the sake of step-by-step demonstartion):

```
select filter,
@row_count:=length(replace(filter,',','')) -- note: Don't use alias for @row_count, because @row_count being a user variable has session-level scope which is wider.
from y
join (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 ) t
on n<=length(filter)-length(replace(filter,',','')) + 1
where y.id=1
;

-- result
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| filter | @row_count:=length(replace(filter,',','')) |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| a,d    |                                          2 |
| a,d    |                                          2 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Next, we use `subtring_index` function to separate the comma-delimited string and put the result into different rows. The query does what the recursive CTE does in the above solution for MySQL8.0 .(Yes, we are trying to simulate a recursive CTE using standard SQL.)

Here is the query:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(filter,',',t.n),',',-1) as f,
@row_count:=length(replace(filter,',','')) 
from y 
join (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 ) t
on n<=length(filter)-length(replace(filter,',','')) + 1
where y.id=1
;

-- result
+------+--------------------------------------------+
| f    | @row_count:=length(replace(filter,',','')) |
+------+--------------------------------------------+
| a    |                                          2 |
| d    |                                          2 |
+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Since we have the same derived table just like the previous recursive CTE, the rest is the same searching and comparing job. This is the complete query in one go:

```
select * 
from x 
where     ( select count(*) 
            from (select substring_index(substring_index(filter,',',t.n),',',-1) as f,
                                @row_count:=length(replace(filter,',',''))  
                                from y 
                                join (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 ) t
                                on n<=length(filter)-length(replace(filter,',','')) + 1
                                where y.id=1) tb
            where locate(f, value)>0 )  >= @row_count
; 

-- result
+----+---------+
| id | value   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a,b,c,d |
|  3 | a,c,d   |
|  5 | a,d     |
+----+---------+
```

Let's try again using y.id=2 this time:

```
select * 
from x 
where     ( select count(*) 
            from (select substring_index(substring_index(filter,',',t.n),',',-1) as f,
                                @row_count:=length(replace(filter,',',''))  
                                from y 
                                join (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 ) t
                                on n<=length(filter)-length(replace(filter,',','')) + 1
                                where y.id=2) tb
            where locate(f, value)>0 )  >= @row_count
; 

-- result
+----+---------+
| id | value   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a,b,c,d |
|  3 | a,c,d   |
+----+---------+
```

**CONCLUSION** 
This one without recursive CTE is definitely trickier. We have to manually create a sequence table using UNION to create enough rows to accomodate the individual values after the comma-delimitered string is separeted. And to circumvent the hassle caused by a user trying to modify the comma-delimitered string(e.g expanding the orginal string) , we should make the UNION sequence table larger than required in case extra rows are needed than the original plan. The extra table size may not impact the performance much, but still a waste nonetheless.

Comment: wow... thank you for your detail explanation blabla_bingo.  Unfortunately, at this time I haven't upgraded to MySQL version 8.

Comment: @HandyCreative Check the updated section.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ***Paul Maxwell***, ***user2260040***, ***ooxvyd*** for the answer.
I will split table Y as a Row.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `x`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `x` 
SELECT 1 as id, "a,b,c,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 2 as id, "b,c" as `value`
UNION SELECT 3 as id, "a,c,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 4 as id, "a,b,c" as `value`
UNION SELECT 5 as id, "a,d" as `value`
UNION SELECT 6 as id, "b,d" as `value`;
SELECT * FROM x;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `y`; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `y` 
SELECT 1 as id, "a" as `filter`
UNION SELECT 2 as id, "d" as `filter`;
SELECT * FROM y;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `y2`; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `y2` 
SELECT * FROM `y`;

SELECT x.id, x.value
FROM x
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM y
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(y.filter, x.value)
) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM y2);
```